# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The FROM clause of the query does not declare an identification variable [foo]

Tags: jpa, jpql

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [select t from Utilisateur t where LOGIN='' and PASSWORD=''], line 1, column 34: unknown identification variable [login]. The FROM clause of the query does not declare an identification variable [login].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1477)
    at ejbservice.GestionUtulisateur.authentification(GestionUtulisateur.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

what is my error please help me and this is my method

```
public boolean authentification(String login, String password) {
     String a = "select t from Utilisateur t where LOGIN='"+login+"' and PASSWORD='"+password+"'";
     EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProjetPU");
     EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
     Query query = em.createQuery(a);
     List <Utilisateur> Loaded = query.getResultList();
     if ((Loaded.size())==0 ){
         return false ;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Are `LOGIN` and `PASSWORD` *property* names of Utilisateur? If they are, you should be using `t.LOGIN`, `t.PASSWORD`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect. Assuming that your `Utilisateur.java` actually does have properties named `LOGIN` and `PASSWORD`, you would use a JPQL expression like:

```
select t from Utilisateur t where t.LOGIN='...' and t.PASSWORD='...'
```

I'm guessing. But those seem like table column names to me (because of the convention of declaring properties as lowercase). Check if you are not mixing up columns with properties.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JPQL query so you should use setParameter to pass the argument :
try this :

```
String a = "select t from Utilisateur t where LOGIN= :loginParam and PASSWORD= :passwordParam";
Query query = em.createQuery(a);
...
query.setParameter("loginParam",login);
query.setParameter("passwordParam",password);
List <Utilisateur> Loaded = query.getResultList();
...
```